# t-test to check difference between means. Non-binomial metric

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, mean, ab-test

I’d like to run A/B test to test average revenue per user (ARPU). As far as I understood, ARPU is non-binomial metric which has a distribution form looks like a very "aggressive" form of exponential. I’ll have at least 10 000 observations in each group. So, is it possible to use t-test in this case? Is it possible to use t-test in case of non-binomial distribution or is it better to use other test?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you help confirm: you're going to compare ARPU for two different strategies, and for each strategy, you'll have at least 10,000 users to test it out on?

Comment: Hello, John. Yes, you are right: I'll have at least 10,000 users in each group to compare ARPU. One group with changes (B - test) and one without changes (A - control).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. In that case, two comments: 1) with samples of this size, we are very likely to get a significant p-value if we conduct a t-test, even if there's not that big a difference between the two strategies. Probably best to try to build a confidence interval on the difference to guide biz decisions. 2) With so many data, if we're set on a significance test, why use any parametric assumptions? Might as well use a nonparametric test to compare.

Comment: Could you please help me to clarify how to interpret comparison using confidence intervals? I calculate percentile confidential intervals for both groups. And after it we can say that changes are significant only in case these intervals don't have intersections at all?

Comment: I got such intervals: A: [0.364; 0.415]; B: [0.346; 0.397]. 
So it means that changes are randomness, doesn't it?

Comment: yes that's the right conclusion. I imagine a p-value would be above 0.05.